# Typescript: Dynamically adding a group of input fields only returning first letter from input?

Tags: typescript, forms

I'm trying to dynamically add a group of input fields using typescript. By applying the React/pure JS approach, I'm only able to get the first letter entered into the input field. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. It's working where I'm collecting data from a single input field but doesn't seem to like it when I'm trying to update a multiple inputs at the same time.

Here's what I have right now:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([{
     name: "",
     email: "",
     age: 0,
}])

const handleAddAnotherUser = () => {
     setInfo([...info, {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        age: 0,
     }])
}

const handleUser = (i: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    let newInfo = [...info] as any;
    newInfo[i][name] = value;
    setInfo(newInfo);
}

return (
    <>
        {info.map((item, i) => (
            <div>
                <input
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Joe Bloggs"
                    value={item.name}
                    onChange={(event) => handleUser(i, event)}
                />
                <input
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="hello@email.com"
                    value={item.email}
                    onChange={(event) => handleUser(i, event)}
                />
                <input
                    id="age"
                    name="age"
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="34"
                    value={item.age}
                    onChange={(event) => handleUser(i, event)}
                />
           </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={handleAddAnotherUser}>Add Another</button>
    </>
)
```

I tried adding `setInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));` or similar syntax in various places within the `handleUser` callback function but everything I tried produced some error or other.